# want to Make software router having two nic cards using centos 6.4

Tags: domain-name-system, nat, centos6, gateway, ip-routing

I'm new on CentOS. I have a CentOS 6.4 system having 2 NIC cards. I want to setup a gateway so I can get internet from public ip over 1st nic card (eth1) and forward the network over 2nd nic card (eth2) so it can be accessible to my local network. I made a DNS server in same system. my gateway system is able to ping to both DNS and google but my client systems are not.

I tried to set the iptables rules it works ping to local gateway but unable to ping to public DNS and www.google.com from client system..when I ping to google.com said that host is unreachable.

How can I implement this, please help me?

- public ip is(eth1) : x.x.x.x
- my local network is (eth2) : 192.168.x.x

I used this for setting up iptables:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth2 -j ACCEPT

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination          Gateway             Genmask           Flags     Metric      Ref    Use Iface
local ip             0.0.0.0             255.255.255.0       U        0          0        0 eth2
public ip            0.0.0.0             255.255.255.0       U        0          0        0 eth1 
0.0.0.0         my local gateway         0.0.0.0             UG       0          0        0 eth2
```

Iptables:

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 9761 packets, 1239K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 14666 packets, 1001K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  345 41722 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      Auto_eth1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 15011 packets, 1043K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Please tell me what are changes I have to do in configuration.

Comment: Show output of the # iptables -L -v -n and # iptables -t nat -L -v -n

Comment: Have you considered using a [Firewall Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_router_or_firewall_distributions) that's built on CentOS, with a pretty GUI to make things *easier* to configure?

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. always try to provides as much information as possible when asking question: distro you are running, your configuration, what have you done so far, what is goal etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ip route del default
ip route add default via INTERNETGATEWAY dev eth2
```

There is something screwy with your route. the centos 'NAT' box needs to sit on two nets:

```
192.168.5.x/24 (Private eth2)
192.168.6.x/24 (Public eth1)  -- hypothetically
```

your route should be something like:

```
ip route add route 192.168.5.0/24 dev eth2
ip route add route 192.168.6.0/24 dev eth1
ip route add default via 192.168.6.1 dev eth1
```

Right now you are routing internet bound traffic out of your private facing NIC...

Comment: Thanks lVlint67,  but in this case which DNS address i preferred to use according to my network.can i use public DNS or my private DNS for eth1 and eth2.

Comment: List what ever nameservers you want in /etc/resolv.conf. Your issue though is with your routing table and specifically your default route.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Ditch trying to roll it by hand and use an appliance product such as [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/) that handles this very well.

Yes, it is possible, but if you're not familiar with how this all works it's not worth your time to try to build it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

To setup PBR (Policy Base Routing) you could use the following script

```
#!/bin/sh

IF1='eth1'
IP1='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
GW1='xxx.xxx.xxx.254'
P1_NET='xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/30'

IF2='eth2'
IP2='yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy'
GW2='yyy.yyy.yyy.254'
P2_NET='yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy/30'

/sbin/ip route add $P1_NET dev $IF1 src $IP1 table ISP1
/sbin/ip route add default via $GW1 table ISP1

/sbin/ip route add $P2_NET dev $IF2 src $IP2 table ISP2
/sbin/ip route add default via $GW2 table ISP2

/sbin/ip rule add from $IP1 table ISP1
/sbin/ip rule add from $IP2 table ISP2

/sbin/ip route add default via $GW1
/sbin/ip route flush cache
```

**Note:** before running the script you must create tables ISP1/ISP2

```
# echo "10 ISP1" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# echo "20 ISP2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

Mark necessary packets

```
# iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.1 -m conntrack --ctorigdst xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j MARK --set-mark 0x1

# iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -s 192.168.1.1 -m conntrack --ctorigdst yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy -j MARK --set-mark 0x2
```

Setting up own routes for each of ISP

```
# ip ru add fwmark 0x1 lookup ISP1 prio 1000
# ip ru add fwmark 0x2 lookup ISP2 prio 2000
```

where is xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy your public ip addresses

Disable Reverse Path Filter

```
# echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/rp_filter
```